# SQL Query -Select Where Description and Value Greater

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query that is returning most of what I need, but I need a little help with, what I assume, is a WHERE statement.

```
SELECT
      C.NameOf AS 'Client',
      CV2.DescriptionOf,
      VC.Limit1 AS '1st Limit',
      VC.Limit2 AS '2nd Limit'

FROM Policy AS P 
--And a Bunch of other Joins

WHERE CV2.DescriptionOf IN ('Underinsured/Uninsured Motorists BI', 
    'Bodily Injury Liability','Combined Single Limit Liability',
    'Property Damage - Single Limit')
```

And return me the following client info (Displaying 1 client)

```
Client      DescriptionOf       1stLimit    2ndLimit    
John Doe    Uninsured Motorists 25000       25000       
John Doe    Property Damage     50000               
John Doe    Bodily Injury       25000       25000
```

What I need I guess is a WHERE Clause that will return the rows where the Description is "Uninsured Motorists" **and** the 1stLimit is greater than the 1stLimit field of the other 2 rows.
And the same of the 2ndLimit field. So essentially it will return the following...

```
Client      DescriptionOf       1stLimit    2ndLimit    
John Doe    Uninsured Motorists 25000       25000       
John Doe    Property Damage     50000
```

Any Thoughts?

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2016

Comment: Will there always be three such rows?  Never two, never four?

Comment: No more that 4 rows for the same client /  vehicle #, but could be as few as 2 rows.  Essentially, I need to provide a list of all clients that the Uninsured Motorists coverage at lease matches the other coverages.

Comment: Why do have "Property Damage" in your example output?  That doesn't meet the description requirement or the 1stLimit requirement

Comment: Sorry, corrected the sample.  I need where the UM Limits are at least the same or greater of the other coverages..

Comment: Sorry, but your example still doesn't make sense.  I don't see why those two rows were returned.

Comment: Because the 1st Limit of the Uninsured Motorists does not equal or is less than the 1st Limit of the Property Damage Coverage.  I need to make sure that the Uninsured Motorists coverage on all clients is at least equal to (or greater than) the other coverages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm modifying my answer, this will look to see if Uninsured Motorists VC.Limit1 is less than any of the other plans (CV2.DescriptionOf). Note: this is guessing because I have to make a lot of assumptions in the bunch of other joins part.

```
SELECT
  C.NameOf AS 'Client',
  CV2.DescriptionOf,
  VC.Limit1 AS '1st Limit',
  VC.Limit2 AS '2nd Limit'

FROM Policy AS P 
--And a Bunch of other Joins
inner join (select max(VC.Limit1) as MaxLimit, C.NameOf as ClientName 
        from VC --And a Bunch of other Joins
        where CV2.DescriptionOf != 'Uninsured Motorists' 
        group by C.NameOf) m
on m.ClientName = C.NameOf
WHERE CV2.DescriptionOf = 'Uninsured Motorists' 
  and VC.Limit1 < MaxLimit
```

Comment: That's my problem it's not VC.Limit1 > VC.Limit2.  It's VC.Limit1 > VC.Limit1 Based on the DescriptionOf field.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using a CTE and a union

```
; with
    CTE as (
        SELECT  C.NameOf AS 'Client',
                CV2.DescriptionOf as 'Description',
                VC.Limit1 AS 'FirstLimit',
                VC.Limit2 AS 'SecondLimit'
            FROM Policy AS P 
            --And a Bunch of other Joins
            WHERE CV2.DescriptionOf IN ('Underinsured/Uninsured Motorists BI', 'Bodily Injury Liability', 'Combined Single Limit Liability', 'Property Damage - Single Limit')
    )
select *
    from CTE p
    where FirstLimit = (
        select MAX(FirstLimit)
            from CTE
            where Client = p.Client
    )
union
select *
    from CTE
    where Description = 'Uninsured Motorists'
```